# Rename a lot of files in subdirectories with multiple file extenisons

Tags: file, rename

So I have a very big folder full of more folders which hold files that all have their regular extension, but then with ,v after it (like .xml,v)

Is there a quick way/program to make it go through all of the folders and when it finds a ,v it'll remove the ,v from it?

Thanks

EDIT: I am running Windows 7 (64-bit). Also please remember than I am an idiot :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use find to list the files ending `,v`. Pipe the output to a shell loop that renames the files.

`${f%%,v}` matches the file name without the `,v` suffix.

```
find . -name \*,v | while read f; do mv $f ${f%%,v} ;done
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear, Where you have the files? (In your computer / on a server).
What is the platform (Windows / Linux) ...

There are multiple ways to solve it based on scenario (like a tiny batch file can do it in a flash if the folder is in your local computer with windows platform) ...